# C# There is no row at position 0

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Im getting the error once again stating there is no row that matches the SQL query.

It states:

> There is no row at position 0.

The points at:

```
 firstnameTxt.Text = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
```

The following is my C# code.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["New"] != null)
        {
            redPnl.Visible = false;
            UserNameSess.Text += Session["New"].ToString();

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Student_Username, Student_FName, Student_SName, Student_Email FROM Student Where Student_Username=@StuUsername", con);
            sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@StuUsername", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserNameSess.Text;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)

            usernameTxt.Text = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
            firstnameTxt.Text = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
            surnameTxt.Text = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[2].ToString();
            emailTxt.Text = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[3].ToString();
            dt.Clear();

        }
        else
        {
            redPnl.Visible = true;
        }



    }
```

I have no idea why it is doing it as its honestly bringing back the value and showing it in the textbox.

Comment: One thing: only the first statement after the `if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)` will be safe but you are accessing the rows also later. Surround it in parenthesis. But it's not clear why you get the error if this is true: _"as its honestly bringing back the value and showing it in the textbox"_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to add the curly braces to your `if` clause:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["New"] != null)
    {
        redPnl.Visible = false;
        UserNameSess.Text += Session["New"].ToString();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Student_Username, Student_FName, Student_SName, Student_Email FROM Student Where Student_Username=@StuUsername", con);
        sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@StuUsername", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserNameSess.Text;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {  
           usernameTxt.Text = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
           firstnameTxt.Text = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
           surnameTxt.Text = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[2].ToString();
           emailTxt.Text = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[3].ToString();
           dt.Clear();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        redPnl.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Its always something so small!

Answer (score 3):

You need to enclose the statements under the `if` with a pair of `{}` otherwise the condition will be applied to the immediate next statement only; others will execute as usual

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
  usernameTxt.Text = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
  firstnameTxt.Text = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
  surnameTxt.Text = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[2].ToString();
  emailTxt.Text = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[3].ToString();
}
```

You can omit the `{}` if there is only one statement needed to execute based on the condition, in all other cases you should enclose the statements within the pair of `{}`